# Characterizations of Intervals

Tags: real-analysis

Need some help writing a proper proof for the following example:

Let $I_n:= [0,\frac{1}{n}]$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty I_n = \{0\}$.

We know that $0$ is always contained in the intersection between any interval. If we look at how n increases, we know that the interval gets smaller and smaller and eventually approaches $0$.

I remember learning about a property which stated that the intersection of all intervals is equal to a single point and I feel like I should be using it in this proof.

Could anyone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: the proposition you mean is: for a sequence of closed intervals $I_n$ with $I_{n+1}\subset I_n$ (strictly) $\forall n$ it follows that the intersection contains one point. This should be enough to solve this problem, by just checking the conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x \in I_n$ for all $n$, then it must be true that for all $n$ : $ 0 \leq x \leq \dfrac{1}{n}$. If $x \neq 0$, then $x > 0$. So there is some $n$ such that $x > \dfrac{1}{n}$ due to Archimedean principle, contradiction. So $x = 0$. This means $\bigcap \limits_{n=1}^\infty I_n \subset \{0\}$, and it is clear that $\{0\} \subset \bigcap \limits_{n=1}^\infty I_n$, and the conclusion follows.

Alternately, noting that each set is compact, and the sets are nested, i.e $I_{n+1} \subset I_n$, and $I_n$'s diameter $d_n = \dfrac{1}{n} \to 0$, thus their intersection is a singleton, but $0$ is in the intersection, thus the intersection is $\{0\}$.